# Using Word VBA, Apply Various Heading Styles Based on Number Patterns

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am fairly new to VBA. I tag text with heading styles in large documents from a variety of authors. Is it possible identify a number pattern on a line of bolded text, and apply the appropriate style to that entire line (there is usually a hard return at the end of the line).

For example, often our documents are numbered as shown below, and we tag the text accordingly.

```
1.0 text here     (apply Heading 1)
1.2 text here     (apply Heading 2)
1.2.1 text here   (apply Heading 3)
1.2.1.1 text here (apply Heading 4)

2.0 text here     (apply Heading 1)
2.2 text here     (apply Heading 2)
….and so on
```

I have done a lot of research, but I am not sure if this is possible. We do not use any type of auto numbering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Try this code:

```
Sub ApplyHeadings()
    Dim rg1 As Range
    Dim rg2 As Range
    Dim pos As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dots As Long

    Set rg1 = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rg1.Find
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = "[0-9.]{2,}[!^13]@[^13]"
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute
            Set rg2 = rg1.Duplicate
            dots = 0
            ' isolate the numbering
            pos = InStr(rg2.Text, " ")
            If pos > 0 Then rg2.End = rg2.Start + pos - 1
            For i = 1 To Len(rg2.Text)
                ' count the dots in the number
                If Mid(rg2.Text, i, 1) = "." Then dots = dots + 1
            Next i
            ' apply correct heading level
            Select Case dots
                Case 1
                    If Mid(rg2.Text, 3, 1) = "0" Then
                        rg1.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
                    Else
                        rg1.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
                    End If
                Case 2, 3  ' maybe more...
                    rg1.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading " & CStr(dots + 1))
                Case Else
                    ' do nothing
            End Select
            ' prepare for next find
            rg1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is WONDERFUL thank you!!! I wasn't even sure something like this was a possibility. What a time saver! 

Is there any way I can put a condition in there where it only selects bolded paragraphs? Right now, if there are numbers in the body of the text referencing a particular section, it applies the heading style to that whole paragraph as well.

Thank you again for such amazing help.

Comment: I figured it out and added ".Font.Bold = True" below the line ".MatchWildcards = True", so it would only select lines that should actually be headings. It works almost perfectly now except it will only run if editing  small documents (around 15 pages). If the file is any larger, Word 2010 stops responding.